# How can i use Riak as backend for mod_mam on ejabberd 16.04?

Tags: xmpp, backend, ejabberd, riak, nosql

I want to save all message from Ejabberd chat node to Riak.
How can i use Riak as backend for mod_mam on Rjabberd 16.04?
mod_mam is a Ejabberd module, This module implements Message Archive Management in XEP-0313.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Riak is not supported in current MAM implementation.you can use mnesia or sql for this purpose. https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modmam

Comment: Mnesia and SQL model is relational, So not suitable for MAM.

Comment: Can i wrote module for connect NoSQL to Ejabberd?

Comment: yes you can write custom to connect with Riak(NoSQL).